# How to obtain all variations of an array with elements being zero or one

Tags: arrays, fortran, do-loops

I am going to write a do loop over possible values of an array elements. More specifically I have an array, say `A(:)` with size n and any element of array `A` can be `0` or `1`. I want to iterate over all possible values of elements of `A`. Of course a simple way is

```
do A(1)=0, 1
 do A(2)=0, 1
  ....
   ! do something with array A

 end do 
end do
```

but the size of my array is large and this method is not very suitable. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question... Do you want to have all possible variations of the array with the elements being either zero or one? E.g.: `00`, `01`, `10`, `11` for an array of length two?

Comment: Dear  Alexander, Yes, exactly. I want to have all  possible variations of the array with the elements being either zero or one. But to save the memory I do not want to save all possible configurations in a larger  Matrix.

Comment: How large will the array be?

Comment: 2^30 configurations. Indeed the size of A(:) is 30 and thus the total configurations are 2^30.

Comment: Please also note that you must not change the loop index within the loop! Also, you cannot use elements of an array as a loop counter.

Comment: Related (although not for binary, but for arbitrary values): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285705/permutations-with-repetition-algorithm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544443/getting-the-ith-permutation-of-a-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364332/algorithm-to-create-all-possible-combinations/24364575#24364575.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is binary only, why not (mis-)use integers for this task? Just increment the integer by one for each of the combinations and read out the corresponding bits using [`btest`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/BTEST.html):

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer, parameter  :: n = 3
  integer             :: i
  integer             :: A(n)
  integer             :: idx(n) = [(i, i=0,n-1)] ! bit positions start at zero

  ! Use a loop to increment the integer
  do i=0,2**n-1
    ! Get the bits at the lowest positions and map true to "1" and false to "0"
    A = merge( 1, 0, btest( i, idx ) )
    print *,A
  enddo
end program
```

This simple code fills `A` with all combinations (one at a time) and prints them successively.

```
./a.out 
           0           0           0
           1           0           0
           0           1           0
           1           1           0
           0           0           1
           1           0           1
           0           1           1
           1           1           1
```

Note that Fortran only has [signed integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29), so the highest bit is not usable here. This leaves you up to `2^(32-1)` combinations for (default) 4 byte integers if you start from zero as shown here (array length up to 31).

To get the full range, do the loop in the following way:

```
  do i=-huge(1)-1,huge(1)
```

This gives you the full `2^32` distinct variations for arrays of length 32.

Comment: thank you for your interesting solution. In the future I have to generalize my code for non-binary values. Is there a similar trick if the values of A(i) are 0,1,...,M.?

Comment: @Math-fort Yes, but this general solution has been answered e.g., [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285705/permutations-with-repetition-algorithm) :)

Comment: Dear  Alexander, Is there any way to handle an array of length `2^(32)`? thanks,  :-(