# Algorithm to generate all multiset size-n partitions

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I've been trying to figure out a way to generate all distinct size-n partitions of a multiset, but so far have come up empty handed. First let me show what I'm trying to archieve.

Let's say we have an input vector of `uint32_t`:

```
std::vector<uint32_t> input = {1, 1, 2, 2}
```

An let's say we want to create all distinct 2-size partitions. There's only two of these, namely:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Note that order does not matter, i.e. all of the following are duplicate, incorrect solutions.

- Duplicate because order within a permutation group does not matter:

  ```
  [[2, 1], [1, 2]]
  ```
- Duplicate because order of groups does not matter:

  ```
  [[2, 2], [1, 1]]
  ```

Not homework of some kind BTW. I encountered this while coding something at work, but by now it is out of personal interest that I'd like to know how to deal with this. The parameters for the work-related problem were small enough that generating a couple thousand duplicate solutions didn't really matter.

## Current solution (generates duplicates)

In order to illustrate that I'm not just asking without having tried to come up with a solution, let me try to explain my current algorithm (which generates duplicate solutions when used with multisets).

It works as follows: the state has a bitset with n bits set to 1 for each partition block. The length of the bitsets is `size(input) - n * index_block()`, e.g. if the input vector has 8 elements and n = 2, then the first partition block uses an 8-bit bitset with 2 bits set to 1, the next partition block uses a 6-bit bitset with 2 bits set to 1, etc.

A partition is created from these bitsets by iterating over each bitset in order and extracting the elements of the input vector with indices equal to the position of 1-bits in the current bitset.

In order to generate the next partition, I iterate over the bitsets in reverse order. The next bitset permutation is calculated (using a reverse of Gosper's hack). If the first bit in the current bitset is not set (i.e. vector index 0 not selected), then that bitset is reset to its starting state. Enforcing that the first bit is always set prevents generating duplicates when creating size-n set partitions (duplicates of the 2nd kind shown above). If the current bitset is equal to its starting value, this step is then repeated for the previous (longer) bitset.

This works great (and very fast) for sets. However, when used with multisets it generates duplicate solutions, since it is unaware that both elements appear more than once in the input vector. Here's some example output:

```
std::vector<uint32_t> input = {1, 2, 3, 4};
printAllSolutions(myCurrentAlgo(input, 2));
=> [[2, 1], [4, 3]], [[3, 1], [4, 2]], [[4, 1], [3, 2]]

std::vector<uint32_t> input = {1, 1, 2, 2};
printAllSolutions(myCurrentAlgo(input, 2));
=> [[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 1]], [[2, 1], [2, 1]]
```

That last (duplicate) solution is generated simply because the algorithm is unaware of duplicates in the input, it generates the exact same internal states (i.e. which indices to select) in both examples.

## Wanted solution

I guess it's pretty clear by now what I'm trying to end up with. Just for the sake of completeness, it would look somewhat as follows:

```
std::vector<uint32_t> multiset = {1, 1, 2, 2};
MagicClass myGenerator(multiset, 2);
do {
  std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t> > nextSolution = myGenerator.getCurrent();
  std::cout << nextSolution << std::endl;
} while (myGenerator.calcNext());
=> [[1, 1], [2, 2]]
   [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

I.e. the code would work somewhat like `std::next_permutation`, informing that is has generated all solutions and has ended back at the "first" solution (for whatever definition of first you want to use, probably lexicographically, but doesn't need to be).

The closest related algorithm I found is Algorithm M from Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4 Part 1, section 7.2.1.5 (p. 430). However, that generates all possible multiset partitions. There is also an exercise in the book (7.2.1.5.69, solution on p. 778) about how to modify Alg. M in order to generate only solutions with at most r partitions. However, that still allows partitions of different sizes (e.g. `[[1, 2, 2], [1]]` would be a valid output for r = 2).

Any ideas/tricks/existing algorithms on how to go about this? Note that the solution should be efficient, i.e. keeping track of all previously generated solutions, figuring out if the currently generated one is a permutation and if so skipping it, is infeasible because of the rate by which the solution space explodes for longer inputs with more duplicates.

Comment: Can you just remove duplicates in the input?

Comment: Sure, create whatever state you require (preferably linear in the input size of course).

Comment: I believe I have found an efficient solution. I'll probably have time to implement and test it later this week. Stay tuned :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive algorithm to distribute the elements one-by-one could be based on a few simple rules:

- Start by sorting or counting the different elements; they don't have to be in any particular order, you just want to group identical elements together. *(This step will simplify some of the following steps, but could be skipped.)*

```
   {A,B,D,C,C,D,B,A,C} -> {A,A,B,B,D,D,C,C,C}
```

- Start with an empty solution, and insert the elements one by one, using the following rules:

```
   { , , } { , , } { , , }
```

- Before inserting an element, find the duplicate blocks, e.g.:

```
   {A, , } { , , } { , , }  
                    ^dup^

   {A, , } {A, , } {A, , }  
            ^dup^   ^dup^
```

- Insert the element into every non-duplicate block with available space:

```
   partial solution: {A, , } {A, , } { , , }  
                              ^dup^

   insert element B: {A,B, } {A, , } { , , }  
                     {A, , } {A, , } {B, , }
```

- If an identical element is already present, don't put the new element before it:

```
   partial solution:  {A, , } {B, , } { , , }  
   insert another B:  {A,B, } {B, , } { , , }  <- ILLEGAL  
                      {A, , } {B,B, } { , , }  <- OK
                      {A, , } {B, , } {B, , }  <- OK
```

- When inserting an element of which there are another N identical elements, make sure to leave N open spots after the current element:

```
   partial solution:  {A, , } {A, , } {B,B, }  
   insert first D:    {A,D, } {A, , } {B,B, }  <- OK  
                      {A, , } {A, , } {B,B,D}  <- ILLEGAL (NO SPACE FOR 2ND D)
```

- The last group of identical elements can be inserted in one go:

```
   partial solution:  {A,A, } {B,B,D} {D, , }  
   insert C,C,C:      {A,A,C} {B,B,D} {D,C,C}
```

So the algorithm would be something like this:

```pseudo-code
// PREPARATION  
Sort or group input.              // {A,B,D,C,C,D,B,A,C} -> {A,A,B,B,D,D,C,C,C}  
Create empty partial solution.    // { , , } { , , } { , , }  
Start recursion with empty partial solution and index at start of input.  

// RECURSION  
Receive partial solution, index, group size and last-used block.  
If group size is zero:  
    Find group size of identical elements in input, starting at index.  
    Set last-used block to first block.  
Find empty places in partial solution, starting at last-used block.  
If index is at last group in input:  
    Fill empty spaces with elements of last group.
    Store complete solution.
    Return from recursion.
Mark duplicate blocks in partial solution.  
For each block in partial solution, starting at last-used block:  
    If current block is not a duplicate, and has empty places,  
    and the places left in current and later blocks is not less than the group size:
        Insert element into copy of partial solution.
        Recurse with copy, index + 1, group size - 1, current block.
```

I tested a simple JavaScript implementation of this algorithm, and it gives the correct output.

Comment: Nice idea with the partitions. The problem with spotting a duplicate is that it needs to be generated first. For large inputs with lots of duplicate entries this quickly becomes infeasible, because the number of duplicates is much larger than the total number of solutions.

Comment: @Darhuuk I can see a method where e.g. {A,,}{B,B,}{B,B,}{,,} has an accompanying array like [0,1,1,0] which indicates whether each part is in a group of duplicates, or how many duplicates it has, but it will involve additional space and calculations. I'm still hoping we can find a more elegant solution.

Comment: Regarding the very last block of sets in your answer, you should be able to avoid duplicating `bb0 000` with `000 bb0` by only distributing in descending parts within blocks of identical counts.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I tested a version of the new algorithm without partitions, and it appears to work correctly.

Comment: Great! It's usually a rewarding feeling to figure things out. I think I've lost the train of thought on this question though.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Once I'm nerd-sniped by a question, not even a better solution posted by the asker can stop me! :-)

Comment: @גלעדברקן The pseudo-code algorithm by m69 generates all possible solutions and then purges duplicates, which becomes impossibly slow (think centuries of calculation time) and needs virtually unlimited storage for even moderate input sets. The algorithm I posted generates the next solution in place (so only O(1) storage required for a handful of temporary variables) and never generates duplicates.

Comment: @Darhuuk The new version no longer generates duplicates, but it's probably still slower than your code. (Passing the last-used block variable avoids duplicates.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן The number of solutions quickly becomes huge; distributing 20 numbers into 4 blocks of 5 already gave me an average of 9,380,382 solutions which needed 19,867,495 recursions. Of course, the recursion depth and the number of partial solutions stored in memory is never greater than 20 in this case. But the js version takes more than 10 seconds, so even in a serious language this is never going to be fast enough for larger arrays.

Comment: Well I'm not in any hurry. Who said computers have to get back promptly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my pencil and paper algorithm:

```
Describe the multiset in item quantities, e.g., {(1,2),(2,2)}

f(multiset,result):
  if the multiset is empty:
    return result
  otherwise:
    call f again with each unique distribution of one element added to result and 
    removed from the multiset state


Example:
{(1,2),(2,2),(3,2)} n = 2

11       -> 11 22    -> 11 22 33
            11 2  2  -> 11 23 23
1  1     -> 12 12    -> 12 12 33
            12 1  2  -> 12 13 23


Example:
{(1,2),(2,2),(3,2)} n = 3

11      -> 112 2   -> 112 233
           11  22  -> 113 223
1   1   -> 122 1   -> 122 133
           12  12  -> 123 123
```

Let's solve the problem commented below by m69 of dealing with potential duplicate distribution:

```
{A,B,B,C,C,D,D,D,D}

We've reached {A, , }{B, , }{B, , }, have 2 C's to distribute
and we'd like to avoid `ac  bc  b` generated along with `ac  b   bc`.

Because our generation in the level just above is ordered, the series of identical 
counts will be continuous. When a series of identical counts is encountered, make 
the assignment for the whole block of identical counts (rather than each one), 
and partition that contribution in descending parts; for example,

      | identical |
ac     b      b
ac     bc     b     // descending parts [1,0]

Example of longer block:

      |    identical block     |  descending parts
ac     bcccc  b      b      b    // [4,0,0,0] 
ac     bccc   bc     b      b    // [3,1,0,0]
ac     bcc    bcc    b      b    // [2,2,0,0]
...
```

Comment: I started to write something similar, but found some additional difficulties. If you have input {A,B,B,C,C,D,D,D,D} and you've started creating partial solutions like {A, , }{B, , }{B, , }, and you want to insert the distribution {1,1} for the third element C, then you have to differentiate between identical solutions like {A,C, }{B,C, }{B, , } and {A,C, }{B, , }{B,C, } and differing solutions like {A, , }{B,C, }{B,C, }, which turns out to be not that straightforward.

Comment: @m69 good point. Let's say you controlled that during the distribution round by keeping track of what you're distributing against. Could you give an example where even that kind of control (meaning only during the distribution round) would not be enough?

Comment: I posted the answer I was working on, and added the example that revealed the additional complication.

Comment: @m69 I added a suggested solution to the dilemma you posed of distributing within identical blocks.

Comment: That seems simple enough. Of course, it'll have to deal with multiple identical blocks too... the code could become quite fiddly.

Comment: @m69 can't it deal with multiple identical blocks one at a time?

Comment: Yes, I guess it can. Would you keep track of the identical blocks as soon as they are created and store their status somewhere, or check whether a block is the same as the previous one every time you add something to it?

Comment: @m69 no idea, haven't tried to code it (my first thought was a kind of `takeWhile` that, during the distribution round, would measure how long the block is; so not when the duplicates are generated).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution that makes use of the `next_combination` function presented by Hervé Brönnimann in [N2639](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2639.pdf). The comments should make it pretty self-explanatory. The "herve/combinatorics.hpp" file contains the code listed in [N2639](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2639.pdf) inside the `herve` namespace. It's in C++11/14, converting to an older standard should be pretty trivial.

Note that I only quickly tested the solution. Also, I extracted it from a class-based implementation just a couple of minutes ago, so some extra bugs might have crept in. A quick initial test seems to confirm it works, but there might be corner cases for which it won't.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>

#include "herve/combinatorics.hpp"

template <typename BidirIter>
bool next_combination_partition (BidirIter const & startIt,
  BidirIter const & endIt, uint32_t const groupSize) {
  // Typedefs
  using tDiff = typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIter>::difference_type;

  // Skip the last partition, because is consists of the remaining elements.
  // Thus if there's 2 groups or less, the start should be at position 0.
  tDiff const totalLength = std::distance(startIt, endIt);
  uint32_t const numTotalGroups = std::max(static_cast<uint32_t>((totalLength - 1) / groupSize + 1), 2u);
  uint32_t curBegin = (numTotalGroups - 2) * groupSize;
  uint32_t const lastGroupBegin = curBegin - 1;
  uint32_t curMid = curBegin + groupSize;
  bool atStart = (totalLength != 0);

  // Iterate over combinations from back of list to front. If a combination ends
  // up at its starting value, update the previous one as well.
  for (; (curMid != 0) && (atStart);
    curMid = curBegin, curBegin -= groupSize) {
    // To prevent duplicates, first element of each combination partition needs
    // to be fixed. So move start iterator to the next element. This is not true
    // for the starting (2nd to last) group though.
    uint32_t const startIndex = std::min(curBegin + 1, lastGroupBegin + 1);
    auto const iterStart = std::next(startIt, startIndex);
    auto const iterMid = std::next(startIt, curMid);
    atStart = !herve::next_combination(iterStart, iterMid, endIt);
  }

  return !atStart;
}
```

**Edit** Below is my quickly thrown together test code ("combopart.hpp" obviously being the file containing the above function).

```
#include "combopart.hpp"

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  uint32_t const groupSize = 2;

  std::vector<uint32_t> v;
  v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  v = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3};
  v = {1, 1, 2, 2};

  // Make sure contents are sorted
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

  uint64_t count = 0;
  do {
    ++count;

    std::cout << "[ ";
    uint32_t elemCount = 0;
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
      std::cout << *it << " ";
      elemCount++;
      if ((elemCount % groupSize == 0) && (it != std::prev(v.end()))) {
        std::cout << "| ";
      }
    }
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
  } while (next_combination_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), groupSize));

  std::cout << std::endl << "# elements: " << v.size() << " - group size: " <<
    groupSize << " - # combination partitions: " << count << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit 2** Improved algorithm. Replaced early exit branch with combination of conditional move (using `std::max`) and setting `atStart` boolean to false. Untested though, be warned.

**Edit 3** Needed an extra modification so as not to "fix" the first element in the 2nd to last partition. The additional code *should* compile as a conditional move, so there should be no branching cost associated with it.

P.S.: I am aware that the code to generate combinations by @Howard Hinnant (available at https://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html) is much faster than the one by Hervé Brönnimann. However, that code can not handle duplicates in the input (because as far as I can see, it never even dereferences an iterator), which my problem explicitly requires. On the other hand, if you know for sure your input won't contain duplicates, it is definitely the code you want use with my function above.

Comment: If you're sorting the input only because you need identical elements to be grouped together, you may be interested in this question I asked about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579149/can-an-array-be-grouped-more-efficiently-than-sorted/37579211

Comment: In this case, the contents do need to be sorted in order to be able to properly detect when all possible combinations/partitions have been output. Good questions though!

Comment: @Darhuuk   Very interested in your idea although I did not understand well your C++ code.  I am wondering, is there some room for optimization for the specific size-2 problem?  Thanks.

Comment: I have compiled and tested this solution. It turned out to be wrong. The solution produces duplicate partitions with different orders of pairs. For example, the input `{1, 1, 2, 2}` yields three partitions rather than the correct two: `[ 1 1 | 2 2 ]; [ 1 2 | 1 2 ]; [ 2 2 | 1 1 ]`.

Comment: The 7th revision of this answer handles some test cases, but works incorrectly for the case `groupSize=2`, `v={1,1,2,3,4,5}`. It returns 15 combination partitions rather than the correct 9. When `v={1,2,2,3,4,5}` 12 partitions are returned; for `v={1,2,3,3,4,5}` - 10; for duplicate `4`s and `5`s the output is correct: 9 partitions.

Comment: It's been ages since I've had to use this, so I don't know right away how to solve these wrong outputs. I'd very much love to see an algorithm that handles all those cases correctly!

Comment: The algorithm from \@m69's answer seems to work correctly and can be optimized pretty well for group size 2 (pairs). Pairings is what I am interested in. I've implemented an algorithm similar to yours, but much simpler and optimized as it only deals with pairs, not arbitrary group sizes. The not-yet-fully-optimized version of the algorithm based on \@m69's answer works only 16 times slower in cases where your algorithm works correctly (that is, when there are no duplicate elements).