# Can an array be grouped more efficiently than sorted?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, language-agnostic

While working on example code for an algorithm question, I came across the situation where I was sorting an input array, even though I only needed to have identical elements grouped together, but not in any particular order, e.g.:

> {1,2,4,1,4,3,2} → {1,1,2,2,4,4,3} or {1,1,2,2,3,4,4} or {3,1,1,2,2,4,4} or ...

Which made me wonder: **is it possible to group identical elements in an array together more efficiently than by sorting the array?**

On the one hand, the fact that elements don't need to be moved to a particular location means more freedom to find an order which requires fewer swaps. On the other hand, keeping track of where every element in a group is located, and what the optimal final location is, may need more calculations than simply sorting the array.

A logical candidate would be a type of *counting sort*, but what if the array length and/or value range were impractically large?

*For the sake of argument, let's say the array is large (e.g. a million elements), contains 32-bit integers, and the number of identical elements per value could be anything from 1 to a million.*

---

UPDATE: For languages with support for dictionaries, Salvador Dali's answer is obviously the way to go. I'd still be interested in hearing about old-fashioned compare-and-swap methods, or methods which use less space, if there are any.

Comment: I've long wondered about this one, too. The only in-place algorithms (i.e. those that require constant extra space) I've been able to come up with are are O(n^2) in time, the simplest being similar to selection sort. I'm not yet convinced that there is an O(n log n) general solution, other than sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is to create a dictionary and count how many elements of each time you have. After that just iterate over keys in that dictionary and output this key the same number of time as the value of that key.

Quick python implementation:

```
from collections import Counter
arr = [1,2,4,1,4,3,2]
cnt, grouped = Counter(arr), []  # counter create a dictionary which counts the number of each element
for k, v in cnt.iteritems():
    grouped += [k] * v # [k] * v create an array of length v, which has all elements equal to k

print grouped
```

This will group all the elements in `O(n)` time using potentially `O(n)` additional space. Which is more efficiently (in terms of time complexity) than a sorting which will achieve this in `O(n logn)` time and can be done inplace.

Comment: What if you actually wanted to move the elements of the array into place? This method would then become a counting sort, no?

Comment: @m69 not sure I understood your comment. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this method is as efficient as counting sort (because it basically is a counting sort), but not more efficient. I mean, there's no difference in time efficiency whether you want the sorted output {1,1,2,2,3,4,4} or a grouped output like {1,1,2,2,4,4,3}.

Comment: @m69 no, if you read about counting sort, you will see that the time of execution of counting sort also depends on the difference between maximum and minimum element in your array. In countsort you do not have a dictionary, but an array which will have a size of (max-min). So if you will have an array of `[15, 1, 10^7, 5]` you will still execute close to 10^7 operations. In my case you will still execute somewhere close to 20 operations.

Comment: I understand that it's more efficient than counting sort, but it's still equally efficient whether you want the output sorted or only grouped, no?

Comment: @m69 still no. It will return your elements grouped, not sorted. Sometimes it will be the same, but not always. This is because dictionaries do not order their keys. If you want it to be sorted, you can sort the keys of the dictionary before iterating over them. But then you end up with O(klogk) where k is the number distinct elements in the array.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Steve314 can you show me an example of this: `O(n^2) repeated linear searching can be faster than O(n) hash-based`. Because I actually do not believe this.

Answer (score 7):

Since you asked about comparison-based methods, I'm going to make the usual assumptions that (1) elements can be compared but not hashed (2) the only resource of interest is three-way operations.

In an absolute sense, it's easier to group than to sort. Here's a grouping algorithm for three elements that uses one comparison (sorting requires three). Given an input `x, y, z`, if `x = y`, then return `x, y, z`. Otherwise, return `x, z, y`.

Asymptotically, however, both grouping and sorting require `Omega(n log n)` comparisons. The lower bound technique is information-theoretic: we prove that, for every grouping algorithm expressed as a decision tree, there are `3^Omega(n log n)` leaves, which implies that the height of the tree (and hence the worst-case running time of the algorithm) is `Omega(n log n)`.

Fix an arbitrary leaf of the decision tree where no input elements are found to be equal. The input positions are partially ordered by the inequalities found.

Suppose to the contrary that `i, j, k` are pairwise incomparable input positions. Letting `x = input[i], y = input[j], z = input[k]`, the possibilities `x = y < z` and `y = z < x` and `z = x < y` are all consistent with what the algorithm has observed. This cannot be, since it is impossible for the one order chosen by the leaf to put `x` next to `y` next to `z` next to `x`. We conclude that the partial order has no antichain of cardinality three.

By [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth's_theorem), the partial order has two chains that cover the whole input. By considering all possible ways to merge these chains into a total order, there are at most `n choose m ≤ 2^n` permutations that map to each leaf. The number of leaves is thus at least `n!/2^n = 3^Omega(n log n)`.

Comment: Thanks. Salvador answered the question as I originally posted it, so I accepted his answer, but I appreciate you taking the time to address my additional question.

Answer (score 1):

Any sorting algorithm, even the most efficient ones, will require you to traverse the array multiple times. Grouping on the other hand can be done in exactly one iteration, depending on how you insist your result be formatted two:

```
groups = {}
for i in arr:
    if i not in groups:
        groups[i] = []
    groups[i].append(i)
```

This is an extremely primitive loop ignoring many of the optimisations and idioms probably available in your language of choice, but results in this after just one iteration:

```
{1: [1, 1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3], 4: [4, 4]}
```

If you have complex objects, you can choose any arbitrary attribute to group by as the dictionary key, so this is a very generic algorithm.

If you insist on your result being a flat list, you can achieve that easily:

```
result = []
for l in groups:
    result += l
```

(Again, ignoring specific language optimisations and idioms.)

So there you have a constant time solution requiring at most one full iteration of the input and one smaller iteration of the intermediate grouping data structure. The space requirements depend on the specifics of the language, but are typically only whatever little bit of overhead the dictionary and list data structures incur.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that's an O(n) solution, not a a "constant time" (i.e. O(1)) solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a 2-dimensional array with the 1st dimension being the frequency of each value, and the second dimension is the value itself.  We can take advantage of the Boolean data type and indexing. This also allows us to sort the original array instantly while looping over the original array exactly one time giving us an `O(n)` solution. I'm thinking that this approach will translate well to other languages.  Observe the following base R code (N.B. there are far more efficient ways in R than the below, I'm simply giving a more general approach).

```
GroupArray <- function(arr.in) {

    maxVal <- max(arr.in)

    arr.out.val <- rep(FALSE, maxVal)  ## F, F, F, F, ...
    arr.out.freq <- rep(0L, maxVal)     ## 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 

    for (i in arr.in) {
        arr.out.freq[i] <- arr.out.freq[i]+1L
        arr.out.val[i] <- TRUE
    }

    myvals <- which(arr.out.val)   ## "which" returns the TRUE indices

    array(c(arr.out.freq[myvals],myvals), dim = c(length(myvals), 2), dimnames = list(NULL,c("freq","vals")))
}
```

Small example of the above code:

```
set.seed(11)
arr1 <- sample(10, 10, replace = TRUE)

arr1                                    
[1]  3  1  6  1  1 10  1  3  9  2     ## unsorted array

GroupArray(arr1)    
     freq vals       ## Nicely sorted with the frequency
[1,]    4    1
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    2    3
[4,]    1    6
[5,]    1    9
[6,]    1   10
```

Larger example:

```
set.seed(101)
arr2 <- sample(10^6, 10^6, replace = TRUE)

arr2[1:10]       ## First 10 elements of random unsorted array
[1] 372199  43825 709685 657691 249856 300055 584867 333468 622012 545829

arr2[999990:10^6]     ## Last 10 elements of random unsorted array
[1] 999555 468102 851922 244806 192171 188883 821262 603864  63230  29893 664059

t2 <- GroupArray(arr2)
head(t2)
     freq vals        ## Nicely sorted with the frequency
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    2    3
[4,]    2    6
[5,]    2    8
[6,]    1    9

tail(t2)
          freq    vals 
[632188,]    3  999989
[632189,]    1  999991
[632190,]    1  999994
[632191,]    2  999997
[632192,]    2  999999
[632193,]    2 1000000
```

Comment: I think this is basically an implementation of the concept of a dictionary, as proposed in the accepted answer. Some languages have built-in dictionary functionality, in others you have to roll your own, which I think is what you did.

Comment: It seems you're creating a frequency array of length maxVal, whereas a dictionary is only as long as the number of different values actually encountered, which is more space-efficient.

Comment: @m69, I'm not too familiar with dictionaries, but from your question and subsequent answers, it seems as if I should learn more about them.  And yes, you are right about the length issue of the initial arrays I declare not being efficient. It's pretty cool that a dictionary can do this without creating a larger object than the number of unique vales. This was a fun problem. Also, do you know if the dictionary method returns a sorted object?

Comment: It doesn't, at least not in the languages I know of. That's why it's efficient for this question; it counts things without bothering about what order they're in. (Btw, in Javascript, you can use an array as a dictionary, because the array indexes behave more like keys, i.e. you can do `a["foo"]=1; a["bar"]=1; ++a["foo"];` and then `for (var i in a) do_something(a[i]) `, where i will take on the values `"foo"` and `"bar"`.)