# Works to sort in O(n) if array has

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Possible to sort an array in a worst case run time `O(n)` if the array only contains `k ∈ ℕ>0` (k is a constant) different elements?

The assumption is that it requires constant time to compare an array that has `n` elements in it.

First of all I'd like to understand the task, what they want?
I understand the assumption. But what's exactly meant by *`k ∈ ℕ>0` (k is a constant) different elements*?

Does that mean we got an array and the size of it is `k` and because it says `ℕ>0` the array size cannot be `0`? Is that correct?
If so I don't quite understand why they don't just say array with `n` elements instead of it.

Anyway, that's how I understood it and I would say it's NOT possible to sort this array in worst case run time `O(n)` because if we take a look at bucket sort / radix sort etc. it could be done in `O(n*logn)`.

Comment: *Possible to sort an array in a worst case run time O(n)* At worst you need to compare each item in the list with `log(n)` of them

Comment: But assumption says the compare is done in constant time, so O(n) and not O(log n)

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37579149/4408538) question and the answers provided.

Comment: The problem statement seems poorly expressed. Assuming normal set notation, then k ∈ ℕ>0 means that k is an element of the set of natural (counting) numbers 1 to ∞. Nothing is stated about the type of elements in the array, only that there are only k different elements.

Comment: Please change the title from "Works to sort in O(n) if array has" into something that describes the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the values, you can sort array by putting numbers into "buckets". For each value, you create bucket and you add number to that bucket when you iterate through it. You this with all the numbers and only once, therefore it is done in `O(n)`

---

For example having only numbers from 0-9, you can sort it as following

```
public class SortInBucket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {0,5,1,1,1,1,7,9,3,2,1,2,5,6};
        System.out.println("Result of sorting: " + Arrays.toString(sortInBuckets(x)));
    }

    public static int[] sortInBuckets(int[] arr) {
        List<List<Integer>> sortedNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] sortedArr = new int[arr.length];
        // create buckets 0 - 9
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sortedNumbers.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Found number " + arr[i] + " puting index " + i + " to bucket " + arr[i]);
            sortedNumbers.get(arr[i]).add(i);
            System.out.println("Bucket " + arr[i] + " is having " +sortedNumbers.get(arr[i]).size() + " numbers now." );
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The sortedNumbers (list with buckets) looks like following: " +sortedNumbers );

        //just going through buckets and adding its numbers to sortedArr
        int sortedIndex = 0;
        for (List<Integer> bucket : sortedNumbers){
            for (Integer num : bucket){
                sortedArr[sortedIndex] = arr[num];
                sortedIndex++;
            }
        }

        return sortedArr;
    }
}
```

The code above have this output

```
Found number 0 puting index 0 to bucket 0
Bucket 0 is having 1 numbers now.
Found number 5 puting index 1 to bucket 5
Bucket 5 is having 1 numbers now.
Found number 1 puting index 2 to bucket 1
Bucket 1 is having 1 numbers now.
Found number 1 puting index 3 to bucket 1
Bucket 1 is having 2 numbers now.
Found number 1 puting index 4 to bucket 1
Bucket 1 is having 3 numbers now.
Found number 1 puting index 5 to bucket 1
Bucket 1 is having 4 numbers now.
Found number 7 puting index 6 to bucket 7
Bucket 7 is having 1 numbers now.
Found number 9 puting index 7 to bucket 9
Bucket 9 is having 1 numbers now.
Found number 3 puting index 8 to bucket 3
Bucket 3 is having 1 numbers now.
Found number 2 puting index 9 to bucket 2
Bucket 2 is having 1 numbers now.
Found number 1 puting index 10 to bucket 1
Bucket 1 is having 5 numbers now.
Found number 2 puting index 11 to bucket 2
Bucket 2 is having 2 numbers now.
Found number 5 puting index 12 to bucket 5
Bucket 5 is having 2 numbers now.
Found number 6 puting index 13 to bucket 6
Bucket 6 is having 1 numbers now.

The sortedNumbers (list with buckets) looks like following: [[0], [2, 3, 4, 5, 10], [9, 11], [8], [], [1, 12], [13], [6], [], [7]]
Result of sorting: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

---

As was mentioned by  J.F. Sebastian and Steve314, alghoritms that do this are called Radix sort (more generalized alghorithm) or Counting sort (not as "strong", but more simple and can be used for this example).

Comment: I would like to see this algorithm for sorting N numbers.

Comment: @EdHeal `foreach x (array) { bucket[x]++; } foreach x (indices(bucket)) { foreach i (range(bucket[x])) { output(x); } }`

Comment: Is it correct that `x` is the same size as `n` for this problem?

Comment: When you generalize this, you end up with [radix sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) - multiple passes, bucketing up items according to a particular digit position, doing the most-significant digit first. "Digit" need not mean 0..9 - it could mean e.g. byte. Typically the (maximum) number of digits for any number is fixed, so the number of passes is fixed, so you can call it O(n), though if you support big integers it's O(kn) where k is how many digits/passes (or worse if you can't extract a specific digit from a number in O(1) time).

Comment: Your `sortedArr` contains indexes of the last seen elements i.e., it says whether an element is present in the source array (you could have used a bitset with the same effect). You can't get the sorted result if you don't know how many times each element occurs in the original array. You should [use Counting sort if only 0-9 integers may be present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) instead.

Comment: @Steve314 - radix sort is normally implemented least significant digit first, since it allows the buckets to be concatenated after each pass. In the case of a counting / radix sort, an array or matrix of counts converted into indices allows a temp array of the same size as the original array to be used.

Comment: @rcgldr - yes, you're right, I wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 1):

No, the array has size `n`, but it can contain duplicate elements. There are only `k` unique elements in the array. (Or in other words, `n - k` is the number of duplicates in the array.)