# Grouping elements of a list efficiently

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, time-complexity

Given a list of elements, what's the most efficient way to group elements by some key?

For example, if the input is `{a,c,a,b,c,b,b}`, a valid output could be `{a,a,b,b,b,c,c}` or `{b,b,b,c,c,a,a}`.

Obviously, if the type of the key observes an order, a sorting algorithm could be used which would give us a complexity of `O(nlogn)`.

However, the key may be comparable for equality only but not for order. For example, `typeof(dog) != typeof(cat)` but it doesn't make sense to ask if `typeof(dog) < typeof(cat)`.

Of course, ordering could be forced (e.g. `obj.GetType().ToString()` and using lexical order) but since a strict order is not necessary (only grouping), I was wondering if there's a more efficient way than sorting.

Comment: How much keys do you have? O(n) or much smaller?

Comment: You want "in place" grouping or it's fine to copy the elements and make another sorted list?

Comment: @OhadEytan Number of keys varies but usually it's either close to 1 or close to n. I would prefer an "in place" algorithm as this operation will be done on many inputs.

Comment: If the key can be broken into an ordered sequence of pieces, each of which can only take on a small number of values (e.g., character 1, character 2, etc.), then you can radix sort on them (note that radix sorting *does not* actually involve any `<` or `>` comparisons).  A hashing solution like Fabel's can be viewed as the first pass of a kind of radix sort.

Comment: OTOH if the key has to be treated as a black box, I believe the best you can do is to build up a list of equivalence classes as follows: Start with an empty list of classes L.  For each item x, compare x with some (any) item from each class in L.  If any of these equality tests succeeds, add x to that class; if they all fail, add a new class to L containing just the element x.  After processing all items, L contains one class for each group.  This clearly has worst-case time complexity O(n^2), which occurs when all items are distinct.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579149/can-an-array-be-grouped-more-efficiently-than-sorted

Answer (score 1):

I would use an unsorted linked list and a hash map for inserting points, something like this (in pseudo code):

```
function group_sort(unsorted_list)
  node_map = new hash_map
  sorted_list = new linked_list
  foreach node in unsorted_list
    last_node = node_map.get(type_of(node))
    if last_node found
      sorted_list.insert_after(last_node,node)
    else
      sorted_list.append(node)
      node_map.add(type_of(node),node)
  delete node_map
  return sorted_list
```

Hash map lookup and insert is mostly O(1) and hash map insertion might even be rare depending on your data. Linked list insertion is always O(1). Which makes the function almost O(n), and certainly O(nlogn).

Comment: Nice idea. However, List insertion is O(1) only if it's implemented as a doubley-linked list. If the underlying storage is an array, as is often the case for the popular go-to implementations (e.g. List<T> for C#, ArrayList for Java), then insert is O(n).

Comment: @MikeM: Inserting an element *in the middle of* an array-based list is O(n), but appending it to the end as Fabel does here, is O(1) (amortised).  Also, insertion at the front of a singly-linked list is O(1).

Comment: My example inserts both in the middle and in the end, which both is O(1). And to be clear, I'm talking about a linked list, not an array. Using an array for sorting is very inefficient and would make this function O(n2).

Answer (score -1):

You could insert each item into a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Multiset)